# Next.js "module not found" on vercel deployment only for locally stored images

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

#### Hey everyone,

I just stumbled on this issue: I have a Next.js application that I want to deploy to vercel. It iw uploaded to Github with all the necessary files and on import it auto detects the next app, so I didn't have to set anything put in vercel...

When it tries to deploy it gives me this error:

```
./src/app/sections/ProjectsSection.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/1.jpg'
```

in the stack trace and multiple variations of it:

```
Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 (Hive)
Cloning github.com/PrivFelixKniest/portfolio-website (Branch: master, Commit: ab95fc8)
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 374.527ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 31.4.0
Installing dependencies...
added 342 packages in 15s
116 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Detected Next.js version: 13.4.17
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
Running "npm run build"
> portfolio-website@0.1.0 build
> next build
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
- info Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
./src/app/sections/ProjectsSection.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/1.jpg'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.tsx
./src/app/sections/ProjectsSection.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/2.jpg'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.tsx
./src/app/sections/ProjectsSection.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/3.jpg'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.tsx
./src/app/sections/ProjectsSection.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/4.jpg'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.tsx
./src/app/sections/ProjectsSection.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../resources/images/projects/coronadeaths/1.jpg'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.tsx
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

[npm run build] works and gives me a production build and the app runs fine with [npm run dev]...

This is the folder structure for the example given above:

```
website
|
|src/app
|  |
|  |resources
|  |  |
|  |  |images
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |projects
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |scanrecs
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |1.jpg
|  |
|  |
|  |page.tsx
|  |
|  |sections
|  |  |
|  |  |ProjectsSection.tsx
|  |  |
|  |  |
```

[image: Or the full structure here]

And here is the code for the ProjectsSection component from the example above:

```
import React from "react"
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import Image from "next/image";
import sr1image from "../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/1.jpg"
import sr2image from "../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/2.jpg"
import sr3image from "../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/3.jpg"
import sr4image from "../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/4.jpg"
import cd1image from "../resources/images/projects/coronadeaths/1.jpg"
import cd2image from "../resources/images/projects/coronadeaths/2.jpg"
import pythonIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/kisspng-python-high-level-programming-language-language-5abd4cc1374351.5140760915223553932264.png"
import reactIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/pngwing.png"
import fastapiIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/fastapi.png"
import awsIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/aws.png"
import htmlcssjsIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/htmlcssjs.png"
import jsIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/js.png"
import pytestIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/pytest.png"
import muiIcon from  "../resources/images/techIcons/mui.png"
import reduxIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/redux.png"
import firebaseIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/firebase.png"
import javaIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/java.jpg"
import nextIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/nextjs.png"
import exIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/express.png"
import flutter from "../resources/images/techIcons/flutter.png"
import postgresIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/postgre.png"
import git from "../resources/images/techIcons/git.png"
import mysqlIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/mysql.png"
import vercelIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/vercel.png"
import scikitIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/scikit.png"
import pandasIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/pandas.png"
import numpyIcon from "../resources/images/techIcons/numpy.png"
import {ImageCarousel} from "../components/ImageCarousel"



export const ProjectsSection: React.FC<any> = () => {

  const smallIconsHeight = "35px"
  return (
    <Box id="projects" className="section">
      <Box className="alignContent">
        <Box className="contentContainer">
          <h1 style={{marginBottom: "30px"}}>Projects</h1>
          <Box className="flexCollapse" sx={{display: "flex", width: "100%", justifyContent: "space-between", marginBottom: "30px"}}>
            <Box className="projectGridItem">
              <a href="https://scanrecs.com" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">
                <ImageCarousel images={[sr3image,sr4image,sr1image, sr2image]} />
              </a>
            </Box>
            <Box className="projectGridItem" sx={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center"}}>
              <h2 style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>scanrecs&apos; Website and Artist Dashboard</h2>
              <p style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>This project for Scan Records, an international underground record label for electronic music, contained a homepage, a webstore using payhip.com and an artist dashboard, which collects, aggregates and displays
              key insights into an artists performance.</p>
              <Box sx={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-start", height: smallIconsHeight}}>
                <Image src={firebaseIcon} alt="firebase" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={exIcon} alt="express.js" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "10px", marginLeft: "5px"}} />
                <Box sx={{height: "100%", width: "1px", backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "2px", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={reactIcon} alt="react.js" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={muiIcon} alt="Material ui" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={vercelIcon} alt="vercel" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
              </Box>
              {/** Links */}
              <Box sx={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-start", fontStyle: "italic", margin: "30px 0 15px"}}>
                <h3 style={{marginRight: "10px"}}>Links:</h3>
                <a href="https://scanrecs.com" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">scanrecs.com</a>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <Box className="flexCollapse" sx={{display: "flex", width: "100%", justifyContent: "space-between", marginBottom: "30px"}}>
            <Box className="projectGridItem" sx={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center"}}>
              {/** Text */}
              <h2 style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>Predict Covid Deaths ML Algorithm</h2>
              <p style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>This project is a machine learning algorithm for predicting corona death numbers for a given week based on an infection data set (Kaggle competition). 
              The algorithm was written in Python in a jupyter notebook, primarily using the libraries scikit-learn, numpy and pandas. <i>(Competition place 38/80)</i></p>
              {/** Technologies */}
              <Box sx={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-start", height: smallIconsHeight}}>
                <Image src={pythonIcon} alt="python" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={scikitIcon} alt="scikitlearn" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={numpyIcon} alt="numpy" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={pandasIcon} alt="pandas" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
              </Box>
              {/** Links */}
              <Box sx={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-start", fontStyle: "italic", margin: "30px 0 15px"}}>
                <h3 style={{marginRight: "10px"}}>Links:</h3>
                <a href="https://github.com/PrivFelixKniest/covid-death-prediction/tree/master" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Github</a>
                <a href="https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/Covid19-Death-Predictions/overview" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Kaggle</a>
                <a href="https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/Covid19-Death-Predictions/leaderboard" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Leaderboard</a>
              </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box className="projectGridItem" >
              <a href="https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/Covid19-Death-Predictions/overview" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">
                <ImageCarousel images={[cd1image,cd2image]} />
              </a>
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <Box className="flexCollapse" sx={{display: "flex", width: "100%", justifyContent: "space-between", marginTop: "30px"}}>
            <Box className="projectGridItem">
              <a href="https://scanrecs.com" target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">
                <ImageCarousel images={[sr3image,sr4image,sr1image, sr2image]} />
              </a>
            </Box>
            <Box className="projectGridItem" sx={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center"}}>
              <h2 style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>Project Three</h2>
              <p style={{marginBottom: "10px"}}>This is another project that has been butifully executed and is completely done...</p>
              <Box sx={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-start", height: smallIconsHeight}}>
                <Image src={firebaseIcon} alt="firebase" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={exIcon} alt="express.js" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "10px", marginLeft: "5px"}} />
                <Box sx={{height: "100%", width: "1px", backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "2px", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={reactIcon} alt="react.js" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={muiIcon} alt="react.js" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
                <Image src={vercelIcon} alt="vercel" style={{maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100px", height: "auto", width: "auto", marginRight: "5px"}} />
              </Box>
              {/** Links */}
              <Box sx={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-start", fontStyle: "italic", margin: "30px 0 15px"}}>
                <h3 style={{marginRight: "10px"}}>Links:</h3>
                <a href="https://github.com/PrivFelixKniest/covid-death-prediction/tree/master" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Github</a>
                <a href="https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/Covid19-Death-Predictions/overview" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Kaggle</a>
                <a href="https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/Covid19-Death-Predictions/leaderboard" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} target="_blank" rel="no-referrer">Leaderboard</a>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      
    </Box>
  )
}
```

What am I missing?

Thank you everyone in advance for having a look!

Comment: Can you add the code for the component where you used to import `../resources/images/projects/scanrecs/1.jpg`, along with a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: Yes of course I forgot, thanks for mentioning

Comment: @RobinThomas what  do you mean with project structure? I have a screenshot for the necessary folders in the question?

Comment: Ah, yes. Missed that. Possible for me to see your GitHub code?

Comment: sure thing: https://github.com/PrivFelixKniest/portfolio-website.git

Comment: Are your changes in `master` branch? Coz its building fine for me: https://i.imgur.com/XTMFTif.png

Comment: If your changes are in master itself, then delete your `.next` directory and do `npm run build` again.

Comment: its the same for me, it also works locally and yes, everything is up to date in github, I just pushed and VSCode doesnt give me any diff

Comment: Are you willing to move your images to `public` directory at the root? If you do that, you don't have to import the images anymore (will need to update `src` in `Image`)

Comment: sure I guess I can try that... can I keep the folder structure in /images or does it have to be flat in /public

Comment: You can keep the same structure. Let me add an answer on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because of the inconsistencies in the filename casings of your images.

For Windows, `3.JPG` and `3.jpg` will be treated the same. Which is why it works fine in your local environment.

When you deploy to Vercel, its using a Linux machine to deploy as well as to run your app. But here, the filename inconsistency matter. If your filename is `3.JPG` and you are trying to use `3.jpg`, Vercel will report that it cannot find your image.

To solve this issue, make sure you are using the correct filename casing for your files as well as when you use the image in your Next.js code.

---

On a side note, you can keep your images in the `public` directory, rather than bundling it along with the code.

1. Move your images from `src/app/resources/images/*` to `public/images/*`. You can keep the same directory structure inside `public` directory.

As an example: `public/images/decals/creativityproductivity.png`.

2. Remove the `import` of that image
3. Update your `<Image />` component to use:

```
<Image
  src="/images/decals/creativityproductivity.png"
  ...
/>
```

Comment: unfortunatly, while this does technically let me deploy it introduces a new issue, where some images are not being loaded (exactly the ones that vercel complained about before) see deployed app https://portfolio-website-d1kgiz8cd-privfelixkniest.vercel.app

Comment: Interesting. Let me dig a bit further.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, i would think that maybe there is a reserved name that causes issues, that its the data format or something else, i think all of the images that dont work are .jpg (written .JPG for some reason), whereas the others are.png, I will try that

Comment: Yes! Thats the issue. I was just coming to comment it

Comment: Because `next` is looking for the path: `/projects/scanrecs/3.jpg` (used here https://github.com/PrivFelixKniest/portfolio-website/commit/81b26071202fc826dc90327e9a72b9a5be89cd01#diff-63c8a6ff8ed9a81bd79e9ac48699c6f0420e863a734e093c15296614c8639bfdR19). But it's `3.JPG` instead, which it wont find.

Comment: The issue is: it does work locally... only on vercel this becomes an issue, and - Windows actually auto capitalises .jpg to .JPG, even if the file is called .jpg when you are not in "file name editing mode", at least on my system... git doesnt even flag the difference...

Comment: Vercel is using Ubuntu for deployment, where the case of the letters matter. In Windows, it doesn't matter, which is why it's working in your local.

Comment: Can you make sure you use the same extension name with same case, for the impacted images (use the same case in your PR)? The issue will be fixed after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight! Could you please add another answere for this issue so I can upvote it?